# Are there still Sample Bots available in Composer?

Tags: botframework

In the docs it says there are supposed to be eleven sample bots that are supposed to appear on the [Composer homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QmpV.png)

But when I open Composer [the examples are no longer there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJaCy.png)

I tried looking around Composer to find them to no avail, so I was wondering if these samples are still available and if so where could I find them?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on **'+ Create new'** option in the homepage, you can find the templates which are currently available in C# and Node.

[image]

If you need any other template, then you can request for the same using the link on the bottom left.